# Что не так с поиском элемента по дочернему значению в Firebase?

Tags: c#, unity3d, firebase

У меня есть код (в username я передаю "Payziii"):

```
public IEnumerator GetName(string  username)
    {
        var user = db.Child("users").OrderByChild("name").EqualTo(username).GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => user.IsCompleted);

        if(user.Exception  != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(user.Exception);
        }
        else if(user.Result == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Not found.");
        }
        else
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = user.Result;
            Debug.Log(snapshot.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

[Что лежит в бд в Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eOmt.png)

Мне надо, чтобы через `Debug.Log();` вывело значение "name", но оно выводит совсем другое:
[Скриншот вывода в консоль](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5xf9.png)

Comment: OrderByChild("name") - это сортировка. Вам наверное нужен EqualTo. Но даже это не означает, что вам вернётся только значение одного поля. Как вернуть одно поле, я с налёта не понял. Предлагаю вытащить его из возвращаемого объекта. Возможно в нём только это поле и будет.

Comment: Другие проблемы: 1. вам нужен Enumerable или метод должен вернуть одно значение? 2. Используйте async-await. 3. Используйте типы. Возвращайте string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение:
Надо было заменить строчку `Debug.Log(snapshot.Value.ToString());` на `Debug.Log(snapshot.Child(username).Child("name").Value.ToString());`

Также для вывода json-строки можно использовать `Debug.Log(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());`